# Несколько текстовых редакторов на 1й странице WP

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Написал плагин для WordPress.
Создал для нее страницу в админке, в которой подключаю несколько текстовых редакторов через wp_editor.
Все бы ничего, но нормально работает только первый редактор на странице, остальные - нет.
В JS-консоле нет никаких ошибок, использую TinyMCE Advanced.
Можно ли их как-то подружить, или придется разделять на разные страницы?

Comment: У wp_editor() воторой параметр - $editor_id. Он должен быть разный.

Comment: спасибо большое!)